# r shiny plot data between specific dates

Tags: r, shiny, linechart

Kindly excuse my question as I am learning r and shiny. 
I am working on Walmart dataset which has more than 45k rows. What I want to do is that using shiny in R I want to plot a line chart but between specific dates. e.g in my data set I have weekly sale figures in a column named weekly sales. I am able to plot the line chart from 2010 to 2013 using below code, but that chart is too congested. My code is as under:

```
# ui.R

library(shiny)
library(plotly)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Store Data"),
  sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("state",
                "State Name",
                choices = c(unique(
                  as.character(myData$state)
                ))),
    selectInput("deptname",
                "Department Name",
                choices = c(unique(
                  as.character(myData$deptname)
                ))),
    dateRangeInput("dates",
                   "Select Dates",
                   start = "2010-01-01", end = "2013-12-31"),
    radioButtons("plotType", "Plot type",
                 c("Scatter"="p", "Line"="l")
    )
  ),

  mainPanel(plotOutput("statelinePlot")))
))
```

My server file is as under:

```
#server.R

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$statelinePlot <- renderPlot({
    plot(
      myData$store, 
      myData$dept, 
      type = input$plotType
      #input$dates[1], input$dates[2]
    )

  })

})
```

I am a bit confused as how to take the date range from user and make the chart interactive.

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Regards,

Comment: Add this line at the beginning of the `renderPlot`, just before `plot(...` : `myData <- myData[ myData$sale_date >= input$dates[1] & myData$sale_date <= input$dates[2], ]` -  Replace `sale_date` by actual filed name

Comment: @HubertL thanks a lot for the solution. I have managed to make it interactive and can change the dates to see the range data in the plot.

Comment: Congrats! Next thing you should do is read about `?reactive` or [Shiny tutorial](http://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/lesson6/)

Comment: Thanks @HubertL Thanks for the suggestion. I have gone through the Shiny Tutorial you mentioned but I am a bit confused as in my code I have not used reactive function but as soon as I use reactive as suggested in your tutorial my code stops working and get an error <br> object of type 'closure' is not subsettable <br/>
I have written the reactive function like this:
    myData <- reactive({
      myData[ myData$weeklysales >= input$datesid[1] & 
                myData$weeklysales <= input$datesid[2], ]
  })

Comment: This error usually happens when you call a reactive without parenthesis (use this syntax `reactive_data()$field_name`)